# how can I get an element to match the width of another element?

Tags: html, css

So i'm making a webpage...

view here... www.girlzwithmoustaches.com/home2

I have a top social media icon banner which i made inside of a "header"...

The css is below.. Now i want the top banner to match the width % of the image below... So when the user resizes the window, or based upon their browser window size, the top banner of the social media icons will stay aligned with the right most portion of the image slideshow below it..

please help. how can i do this.. The social media icons are a basic ul with li and

```
 #headerwhat {
position: absolute;
top: 30px;
left:100px;
width: 70%;
height: auto;
vertical-align: middle;
horizontal-align: middle;

}

.smbanner {
width: 200px;
height: 50px;
position: relative;
float:right;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;

}

.smicons {
display: inline-block;
padding: 3px;
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/AyD5y/1/embedded/result/

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the same percentages if you want the widths to match.

So, if you have `width: 70%` for `#headerwhat`, the only way to get them to dynamically resize together is to set `.smbanner`'s `width` to `70%`.

Is that what you're asking?

Answer (score 0):

put the image inside the header and give 100% width to the top banner